# How to plot increasing functions in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I plot functions like these ones:
https://www.math24.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/increasing-function.svg
https://www.math24.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/decreasing-function.svg

I know the following method for plotting a specific function:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\begin{axis}[
x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm,
ticks=none,
axis lines=middle,
xmin=-1.080000000000009,
xmax=5.919999999999983,
ymin=-1.199999999999982,
ymax=3.1000000000000054,
ylabel={$y$},
xlabel={$x$},]
\clip(-1.08,-2.02) rectangle (5.92,3.1);
\draw[line width=1pt, smooth,samples=100,domain=-0.780000000000009:5.119999999999983] plot(\x,{sin(((\x))*180/pi)+0.3});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

However, I can't find the formulas for the functions in the pictures shown. Is there anyway I can plot something that insipires an increasing function (but not strictly increasing) just like in the pictures? Also, I would like for the style of the graph to be just like the one in the code above, as I need it for an article and I should perserve the same style all over the article. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
 \draw[->] (-1,0) -- (4,0) node[below left] {$x$};
 \draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,4) node[below left] {$y$};
 \draw[thick,blue!80!black] 
  (-0.5,0.5) to[out=45,in=180] (1,1) to[out=0,in=180] 
  node[midway,above left] (f){$y=f(x)$}(2.5,3) -- (3.5,3);
 \path (0,0) node[below left] {$0$} (f)
 node[above=2em,font=\sffamily,align=center] {increasing\\ function}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you!